# Download symfony2 documentation as html pages

Tags: php, symfony, web

I want to download symfony2 documentation as if it was a FAQ.
I want take advantages of `php | twig | annotation` examples
Is there any way of doing it

Comment: I believe there is a website that spends its time reading in manuals and producing PDF versions, on an automated basis. I can't remember what it is called, maybe someone else will?

Comment: Hmm... http://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony_book_2.5.pdf?v=4

Comment: Thanks but actually is the PDF download URL

Comment: Ah right, I'd not spotted you want HTML. Personally I prefer PDF for offline viewing.

Comment: Yeah! But not comming with XML && ANNOTATION examples

Answer (score 3):

You can find the documentation in RST (reStructuredText) format at https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs

From a RST document, you can easily convert it into HTML with DocUtils for example